# using the select2 javascript library

Tags: javascript

Manage mouse hover and automatic option selection

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select2-container', function() { 
   $(this).prev("select").select2("open"); 
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.select2-container', function() {
    $(this).prev("select").select2("close");
});
```

There is automatic scrolling of the list but it disappears immediately so that I cannot select